# Passing selected option to the button to perform an action using vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a `select` element that contains some `options` elements built from an array.
Right now, when I select an option it immediately calls the function and produces the output but what I want is that once I select any option, and if that option's value is "students" then only it should run the function instantly.
When I click on the `add` button it does not work at all.

---

```
                <form name="Form1" >
                    <b>Field Name</b> : <p>Student Council</p>
                    <b>Field Type:</b> <p>List of Links</p>

                    <b>Range:</b><br>
                    <select name="selectOption" id="listSelect" v-model="selected">
                        <option hidden value="">Select a list</option>
                        <option v-for="List in fieldlist" v-if="List.ListName != 'student_council'"> {{ List.ListName}}</option>
                        
                    </select>
                    <button @click="add"> Save </button>
                    <br><br>
                    <b> Student_Council list:</b>
                    {{fieldlist[5].student_council}}</v-list-item>


                </form>
```

```
<script>
            var vm = new Vue({
                el : '#new_list' , // id of the elemnt we ware working on to call it
                data: {
                    selected : null,
                    fieldlist: [
                        {
                            ListName: 'students',
                            Students: [
                                {
                                    StudentName: 'Yousef',
                                    StudentAge: '24',
                                    isStudent: true,
                                },
                                {
                                    StudentName: 'Baqir',
                                    StudentAge: '23',
                                    isStudent: true,
                                },
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            ListName: 'departments',
                            departments: [],
                            
                        },
                        {
                            ListName: 'department_with_most_students',
                            Department_With_Most_Students: [],

                        },
                        {
                            ListName: 'active_students',
                            active_students: [],
                        },
                        {
                            ListName: 'dean',
                            dean: [],
                        },
                        {
                            ListName: 'student_council',
                            student_council: [],
                        },
                        
                        
                              ],
                },
```

```
                methods: { // functions
                    
                    add: function(option){   
                        if(this.selectOption.option.target.value=== "students"){
                        if(!this.fieldlist[5].student_council.includes(this.fieldlist[0].Students)){    
                        this.fieldlist[5].student_council.push(this.fieldlist[0].Students);
                    }else{
                        this.fieldlist[5].student_council.length = 0;
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                    },
                     
                }
```

I tried to call the `select` element to check its option, but this is also not working so far.
I'm expecting if I select the option "students" and click on the `add` button, it should pass the data inside the `students array` to the `student_council` array

Answer (score 0):

I have read your question I think you have to deal with

```
this.selected
```

instead of

```
this.selectOption.option.target.value
```

in vuejs we don't need to deal with name of tag element we deal with v-model
please update me if i miss something